# Density support for different devices like phones and tablets

Tags: playn

It is known problem that on different devices and densities you need to use dp(dpi) for images sizes/ratios etc.

My question is how can i get the device density (dpi) to properly calculate for my images that i can be sure it will display correct on each devices like phones and tablets with different dpi's ??

On pure Android it's simple but with playn ?
Is there any good solution for that? I want to be sure that my game will look fine on each devices...

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use platform-specific APIs to obtain the device density and then make that information available to the game when selecting your textures and laying out your graphics.

PlayN does not, and cannot, magically just make it all work. Android and iOS take differing approaches to display density, and the view size difference between phones and tablets is a dimension largely orthogonal to display density.

Here's an [article on how to handle different sizes and densities on Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).